# how to add delay to mkannotation pin drop

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my map view I set the map to open, then with a delay of 2 seconds the map zooms in to show my mkannotation, what I have been trying to do is to animate the pin dropping once the view is fully zoomed in, but haven't been able to achieve this.

So basically I want to add a delay to the annotation+pin being dropped at my location.

How do I do this?

Code what I have in place currently in ViewDidLoad, the code for the mkannotation is in void - showDetails:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 54.5;
region.center.longitude = -3.5;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 10.0f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 10.0f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

[self performSelector:@selector(zoomInToMyLocation)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:2]; //will zoom in after 2 seconds
}

-(void)zoomInToMyLocation
{
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 51.502729 ;
region.center.longitude = -0.071948;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.19f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.19f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

[mapView setDelegate:self];

DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Design Museum";
ann.subtitle = @"Camberwell, London";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the delegate *before* you set the region your delegate will receive a call to [mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3aregionDidChangeAnimated%3a). That is called many times while scrolling so what you could do is check the map's current center point and when it is close enough to your target center point you add the annotation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
     ............
    haveAddedPin = false;
}


-(void)zoomInToMyLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 51.502729 ;
    region.center.longitude = -0.071948;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.19f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.19f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(Boolean) animated)
{
    if (haveAddedPin == false && mapView.center == the coordinates of the target you are zooming to)
    {
        DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
        ann.title = @"Design Museum";
        ann.subtitle = @"Camberwell, London";
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
        haveAddedPin = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: my mapview delay works, then it zooms in just how I want, problem is I want to delay the pin dropping, I have tried to put that in its own method but it hasnt worked.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Or if you don't want to do that, try the  `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` function that you're already using.

Comment: i didnt understand what you meant, could you possibly post example code?

Comment: any more help? what do I put in place of "haveAddedPin" ? its undeclared

Comment: So declare it. Look at what it is being used for. What would you normally use for something that is either true or false?

Comment: okay, also when I move set delegate to the beginning of viewdidload, the map doesnt animate the zoom at all, just shows the the ocean

Comment: Is it before or after `[super viewDidLoad]`?

Comment: after... I think I removed it back to where it was before, because I cant get the delay on the annotation drop to work. I think I will have to leave it how it was before, wasting too much time, Im new to coding and cant figure it out from the code you provided, a little vague

Comment: Don't give up so easily, if it doesn't work at the start of the `viewDidLoad` try what I originally suggested, set it *before* you set the region. You could try it at the start of `zoomInToMyLocation`. If I wrote the code any more precisely I'd have done your assignment for you.

Comment: Iknow I appreciate the help, only got till today to finish. its my first iphone app, I have learned alot in only 6 weeks or so. I have to get it finished so I will just leave it how it is i think, unless I can solve before end of today. with help of precise code ha I would appreciate that!